# changing csh regexp match code to tcl

Tags: tcl, csh

I need to change the following piece of code in shell to tcl. Please help.

```
if (` expr $_f : proj_lp_ ` == 8) then
```

I need the tcl equivalent of the condition inside the if condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See the [expr manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expr) where is states:

> ```
>   STRING : REGEXP
>           anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING
> ```

So your `_f` variable holds a string and you are comparing it with the litteral `proj_lp_`. The result is the length of the match. In tcl code that could be `if {[regexp {^proj_lp_} $_f]} { ...}` as you only care if it matches. You could also just use `if {[string match "proj_lp_*" $_f]} {...}`. The expr(1) page says this is an *anchored* regexp -- hence adding the caret. Both the examples I have given will only match at the start of the input string (ie: they are anchored).